# Homogeneous Heat Equation with Infinity

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I need to solve the heat equation:

> $$d_tu = \nabla^2u$$ with $0 < x < \infty$ and $0 < y < \pi$.

Boundary conditions: $u(0,y,t) = u(x,0,t) = u(x,\pi,t) = 0$ and $|u(x,y,t)| \rightarrow 0$ as $x$ approaches $\infty$.

I used separation of variables and got the eigenfunction values for $Y$. But now I'm on the $X$ part with

$$X''(x) + \lambda X(x) = 0$$ But this doesn't seem to work because of the infinity boundary condition. **Am I approaching this the wrong way?**

Thanks!

Comment: What was the equation for $Y(y)$? And what was your solution of it?

Comment: @okrzysik I got Y''(y) + $\mu$Y(y) = 0. And the solution is Y = sin(n$\theta$) where $\mu$ = $n^2$ as the eigenvalue. Problem is I can't do the same for X because of the infinity bound it as.

Comment: now you need to do the same thing for your $X(x)$ equation; you can solve it then workout what the eigenvalue must be to give the required behaviour as $x \rightarrow \infty$. HINT: $\exp(- m x),\ m^2=-\lambda$ is one solution to your ODE that meets your boundary condition. $\exp(mx)$ is another solution of the ODE but it doesn't meet the boundary condition as $x \rightarrow \infty$, can you see why?

Comment: @okrzysik right so you can get X(x) = a*exp(mx) + b*exp(-mx). However, X has another boundary condition where X(0) = 0 which would set both constants to 0.

Comment: for you would get a + b = 0, and b = -a and substituting this back into the equation then you would get a * (exp(mx) - exp(-mx)) or a*sinh(mx) which goes to infinity as x goes to infinity so a would have to be 0.

Comment: That is a problem, I didn't see the other boundary condition for $x = 0$, sorry. At the moment I cannot see how to resolve this issue other than by having the trivial solution $u = 0$ (as you have stated)...

Comment: @okrzysik No problem. I managed to get a solution. I just had to use the Fourier Transform, but thanks for helping though :)